# GmailAPI: Does using a batch request count just once or n(items) against the quota?

Tags: gmail-api

If I use the gmail api to batch fetch 100 mails, does that count 500 quota units or 5? If its 500, then what should the queue setting on my App Engine queue.yaml be so I don't hit the 250 quota units/sec rate limit?

Answer (score 3):

It will count as n items and not one. Also, 250 Quota units per sec is for per user. So, if in your batch request, you have different users, each user will have a 250 Unit Limit.

Comment: Also worth noting that is in not a hard cutoff at 250/sec. Google will allow you some slack and go over the limit for a short while.

Comment: So if I batch all the emails for a user, and say it comes to ~1000, then will I get a "Too Many Requests" or will it just take longer to return the results? Is the behavior that batching WILL return results, just take longer, or will it try to do it in a certain time and return an error if it can't complete?

Comment: Never mind: "Using batching is encouraged, however, larger batch sizes are likely to trigger rate limiting. Sending batches larger than 100 requests is not recommended."

Comment: But I just want to clarify, I am pulling messages using the gmail api that match a certain search criteria, say, all uber receipts. My queue contains (user_id). Each task in the queue gets a list of messages until next_page_token runs dry, and then fetches these in batches of 100 at a time. 
I DO NOT need to have any rate limit on my queues, since there is only 1 task per user (and so I don't hit any per-user limits, though the task may take longer), and the only other limit is like 1b msgs/day, which I know I won't hit. Does this mean I can set the rate on the queue (.yaml) to be like 500/s?